# Vocabulary term to model number of individuals of a class in RDF

Tags: semantics, semantic-web, owl, rdfs, vocabulary

I want to model a dataset in RDF with class name as subject and number of individuals present in the class as object. I am thinking of which predicate will be good to model this information

I searched different vocabularies like RDFS,SKOS etc and also in http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/ but couldn't find the apt one.

Any suggestions regarding which vocabulary term will be good to model this information

Comment: I wonder why you need a predicate for that. Then you would need to update that every time you add more objects to the dataset. Is it not easier to calculate that information when it is needed? If you absolutely needs that predicate, you could always create your own predicate in OWL.

Comment: I agree with @magnudae, this is sort of a strange property.  However, if you're looking to do this for an RDFS class (you ask about "individuals of a class in RDF"), why not some `shalini:cardinality` property?  If you do this in OWL, the property will have to be an annotation property.

Comment: [Duplicated on SemanticWeb](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/30550/property-to-model-number-of-instances-of-a-class) (without any answers)